# Why does emission spectrum happen to be visible light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, x-rays

[Emission spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_spectrum) are, to put it simply, light emitted by atoms. But why most of atomic emission spectrums fall in visible light or at least near visible light? Why not X-ray or gamma ray, or radio waves?

Maybe it has something to do with biological evolution? For example, we see these lights because they compose the light that appear in the universe?

Comment: Indeed, why evolve structures to perceive x-rays if there aren't many around?

Comment: I think the question makes more sense if you reverse it. "Why does visible light happen to be the emission spectrum of atoms?".

Comment: Because our eyes evolved to use the light from the sun sun which produces light by <insert what you already know here>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emission spectrum is convenient for vision. The wavelength is short enough that it can resolve small objects. Even shorter wavelengths are ultra-violet but that can damage cells. Some animals can see infrared, but longer infrared and radio waves would lack resolution (ok for detecting a plane, not so good for a gnat). Anyway, X-rays, gamma rays and radio waves are not common in the environment. Visible light is provided by the sun, penetrates air and cloud well enough and scatters off objects reliably.

Crucially, visible light is not absorbed much by water. Since life evolved in the sea, this would have been the only light available. But even for land-based life, the eye contains a lot of water. See [Wikipedia - Liquid water absorption spectrum across a wide wavelength range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water#/media/File:Absorption_spectrum_of_liquid_water.png).

You also have to build an apparatus that can detect the light. The fact that atoms emit visible light easily also means that they absorb it easily which can trigger some chemical change that can be converted to a signal. It's probably harder to evolve a gamma ray detector in an animal.

Comment: "It's probably harder to evolve an gamma ray detector in an animal." Xeelee comes to mind. Heh.

Answer (score 1):

The electromagnetic waves emitted by excited atoms under everyday circumstances involve energy transitions between the outermost electron orbitals. These have a typical energy difference of a couple of electron volts which put their wavelength in the visible range, or near it in most cases.

To get X-rays instead requires a big energy transition, which can happen in metal atoms when you excite a transition between the outermost orbital and one much deeper down in the orbital structure. In this case the energy difference is of order ~tens of kiloelectron volts and the resulting photon has a wavelength in the X-ray band. This means they cannot be triggered by processes involving visible light photons, which are not energetic enough.

To get gamma rays you need an energy transition of order ~millions of electron volts, which can be generated by (extraordinary) processes inside the nucleus of an atom.